1st order model vs 2nd order model in .jmp
How so I explain that my 2nd order model shows a significant relationship between predictors and responses since I had no lack of fit whereas with the same data on a 1st order model I had a significant lack of fit. How do I explain that the 2nd order provides a better approximation of the data? I'm just trying to wrap my head around it as I only have a basic understanding of it at the minute. Thanks in advance.

Can you add the data/graphs/tests to your question, which show that the 2nd order model is a better fit? W/o it,, we are just assuming. Thanks
